In connecting to Github via https, I'm getting the following SSL error
git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/highperformancecoder/civita.git/': OpenSSL/3.0.1: error:16000069:STORE routines::unregistered scheme

I have been working around it by adding the ssh connection string to the git pull or push commands, eg
git pull git@github.com:highperformancecoder/civita.git

This problem first appeared when I upgraded to OpenSUSE Leap 15.6. It is possibly an invalid OpenSSL configuration, but Googling the error message has not provided any information remotely useful.

Can you show us your OpenSSL config file?

I guess you mean /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf. It is too big for this post, but I've uploaded it to https://www.hpcoders.com.au/openssl.cnf

Further to this question, I have found that this issue only affects one of my computers - the one upgraded from OpenSUSE Leap 15.5 to 15.6, whereas the issue doesn't affect the computer that was clean-installed with Leap 15.6.
I have tried mirroring the /etc/ssl and /etc/crypto-policies directory from the good machine to the bad one, without resolving this issue.

SOLVED! I had an old libssl.so.3 library in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH from another project I no longer work on.
It was a curly one!
